# How to resolve reference solutions dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, dependencies

Work on **C#**.Stuck on my application **architectural** issue.Have two solutions named **CalculationManager** and **ContainerManager**.

ContainerManager have reference of CalculationManager and CalculationManager hold other three class library references like the picture.
[image]

Problem is ContainerManager **debug** perfectly but when **run** this project show error message **Could not load file or assembly.**

What to do ? how to break this CalculationManager’s dependencies? Have no idea what to do?

Comment: Are all references being copied ? Clean your solution and build.

Comment: @konkked it is referenced in CalculationManager

Comment: ContainerManager should reference those dependencies of ImplementManager, too.

Comment: @ Haukinger, thanks for your reply.It's not possible to give references of ContainerManager on implementManager solution.

Comment: what is the invoking or calling application?

Comment: Then copy the assemblies over manually, by post build event, perhaps. Or make a nuget-package out of ImplementManager. If ImplementManager needs those assemblies, anyone using ImplementManager needs them, too, or at least, has to provide them.

Comment: @ Haukinger thanks for your reply.CalculationManager have three dependencies suppose i need just one dependent library functionalities then why i use three.Is there any better solution which break the dependencies barriers.Is delegate helpful on this issue.I dont know how to ?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking the dependency"? If ImplementManager uses stuff from MultiplyManager, it depends on it. Period. If you want one single assembly, you could move the code from MultiplyManager to ImplementManager and thus remove the dependency _on another assembly_ (the dependency _on the code_ will remain, of course)

Comment: @ Haukinger as i say before it's not a best solutions.Looking for best one.Hope there must be any design pattern which can solve my issue.

Comment: A design pattern won't magically copy dlls. If you want to run the code, make it available to the executing assembly.

Comment: there are more variables in your issue than this. You could easily debug against one DLL and Deploy another. Check versions. Check properties in the reference, what does it say? Remember, when DLL is built, it has referenced DLL version inside of it. so you better provide one with same version or higher

Answer (score 0):

Check your bin folder in ContainerManager. 
AdditionManager, MultiplyManager and SubtractionManager dll's should've also been added along with ImplementationManager, if not then there's the problem.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply.Please check my question and comments ,Want to break reference class dependencies not try to incorporate them in my implemented class.